# Pyspark: Drop arrays of structs if condition is met

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I've got the following pyspark dataframe:
[image]

I'd like to remove all arrays from the column 'price_history' in which at least one of the following conditions is met:

1. the date is null
2. the price is null
3. the price is 0.00

The expected dataframe looks like this:

[image]

The syntax:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import date

from pyspark.sql.functions import (array, when, array_except, col,
                                   lit, array_size, struct,
                                   max as pyspark_max)
from pyspark.sql.types import (LongType, StringType, StructField,
                               StructType, IntegerType, DateType,
                               DecimalType, ArrayType)


INPUT_SCHEMA = StructType([
        StructField('ID', LongType(), True),
        StructField('brand', StringType(), True),
        StructField('price_history', ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField('date', DateType(), True),
            StructField('identifier', StringType(), True),
            StructField('price', DecimalType(12, 2), True),]),
            True),
            True),
            ])

INPUT_DATA = [
    [7572753287, 'brand 1', [[None, None, Decimal(2.19)],
                                  [date(2023, 2, 27), None, Decimal(1.79)]]],
    [7373874387383, 'brand 2', [[None, "N", Decimal(7.00)]]],
    [223278687678, 'brand 3', [[None, "NB", Decimal(0.63)]]],
    [2782872453, 'brand 2', [[None, "N", Decimal(2.19)]]],
    [86943438343, 'brand x', [[None, "NW", Decimal(1.49)]]],
    [87334273838, 'mybrand', [[date(2022, 3, 26), "NW", None],
                                 [date(2024, 1, 15), "E", Decimal(0.99)],
                                 [date(2024, 1, 15), "E", Decimal(0.00)]]],
    [2783783972, 'other brand', [[date(2024, 1, 15), "NW", None]]],
]


EXPECTED_DATA = [
    [7572753287, 'brand 1', [[date(2023, 2, 27), None, Decimal(1.79)]]],
    [7373874387383, 'brand 2', []],
    [223278687678, 'brand 3', []],
    [2782872453, 'brand 2', []],
    [86943438343, 'brand x', []],
    [87334273838, 'mybrand', [[date(2024, 1, 15), "E", Decimal(0.99)]]],
    [2783783972, 'other brand', []],
]

expected_df = spark.createDataFrame(EXPECTED_DATA, INPUT_SCHEMA)
input_df = spark.createDataFrame(INPUT_DATA, INPUT_SCHEMA)
input_df.display()
```

I already found a way to solve the problem but it seems to be too complicated. It looks like this:

```
max_array_size = input_df.select(pyspark_max(array_size(col('price_history')))).collect()[0][0]
empty_struct = struct(lit(None).cast(DateType()).alias('date'),
                      lit(None).cast(StringType()).alias('identifier'),
                      lit(None).cast(DecimalType(12, 2)).alias('price'))


result = input_df.withColumn('price_history',
                             array_except(array(*[when(
                                                    (col('price_history').getItem(x).getField('date').isNull()) |
                                                    (col('price_history').getItem(x).getField('price').isNull()) |
                                                    (col('price_history').getItem(x).getField('price')==Decimal(0.00)),
                                                    empty_struct).otherwise(col('price_history').getItem(x))
                                                  for x in range(max_array_size)]), 
                                          array(empty_struct)))
result.display()
```

To confirm that both dataframes are equal (requires pyspark 3.5 and pyarrow):

```
from pyspark.testing import assertDataFrameEqual

assertDataFrameEqual(expected_df, result)
```

Is there an easier way of doing this? I was going through all the pyspark functions to find something that helps me to facilitate things but I couldn't find anything :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`price_history` is array of structs, you can use `F.filter` to remove elements from it.

```py
import operator
import functools
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


def my_filter(price_hist: Column) -> Column:
    _preds = [
        price_hist.getField('date').isNull(),
        price_hist.getField('price').isNull(),
        price_hist.getField('price') == F.lit(0.0),
    ]
    condition = functools.reduce(operator.or_, _preds)
    return ~condition


res = input_df.withColumns({
    'filtered': F.filter('price_history', my_filter),
})
res.select('price_history', 'filtered').show(10, False)

# +----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
# |price_history                                                         |filtered                  |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
# |[{null, null, 2.19}, {2023-02-27, null, 1.79}]                        |[{2023-02-27, null, 1.79}]|
# |[{null, N, 7.00}]                                                     |[]                        |
# |[{null, NB, 0.63}]                                                    |[]                        |
# |[{null, N, 2.19}]                                                     |[]                        |
# |[{null, NW, 1.49}]                                                    |[]                        |
# |[{2022-03-26, NW, null}, {2024-01-15, E, 0.99}, {2024-01-15, E, 0.00}]|[{2024-01-15, E, 0.99}]   |
# |[{2024-01-15, NW, null}]                                              |[]                        |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution :). Do you know whether it is possible to add multiple arguments to the `my_filter` function like `date: str` and `price: str` such that `.getField('date')` can be replaced by `.getField(date)`? If yes, how to pass these arguments to the function call of my_filter?

Comment: Hi, you cannot add more arguments to `my_filter` but you can create a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). Basically you need to wrap `my_filter` in another function that takes the additional args and returns the filtering function with the necessary signature.